# Solr search not giving exact result for single word term

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I am a very beginner in solr search queries where I am trying to get exact results for my given term. I am getting exact result  for terms which have more than one word. But for terms which have only one word I am not getting exact search result. Before down voting or closing this question consider the scenario. I am asking exact search for single word.

For ex

1. If I search "ship to add"
   I get result **ship to address**
2. Plant: I get results like Plant Number, Plant Type, Plant description,and then **Plant**
   I want my Exact word Plant to come first then I want other related searches to come

**Approaches I have tried**

```
/query?q=(name:"PLant")&stopwords=true           //giving output I mentiond above

/query?q=(name:"^PLant$")&stopwords=true        //not giving any output

/query?q="PLant"&stopwords=true                //giving fuzzy output
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hits will be determined by the analysis chain for your field - this chain can be a lossy process, so if you're not actually storing the exact tokens, you won't be able to do an exact match. You can't query against stored text directly. You can add a second field and then use `copyField` to copy the same content into that field, and then use that field for boosting those that have exact matches. Also the default behavior is that fields with shorter content (i.e. fewer tokens) will be boosted slightly higher, but that will depend on your settings for the field as well.

Comment: So can you add a demo query for aboce scenario what all you have written in the statement as I am hardly having any expereince with solr

Comment: You'll have to add the definition of the field you're using and how you're querying it - in your third example you don't have a field name, so it'll be using whatever is defined as your default search field (usually `_text_`). If you're using the default `text` field, you'll get the hits you're mentioning. But since you're also saying that you can't edit the schema, I'm not sure what you will be able to change (can you change field names? Add fields? Change types for the fields?).

Comment: OK Some how i have changed schema ```<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />``` like this but results are same

Comment: You'll also have to reindex after changing the field type (in effect cleaning out the index and indexing all documents again). A `string` field will only give exact hits, so if you have `Plant` in that field afterwards, `name:Plant` will only give back documents where that is the exact value.

Comment: How to do reindex after changing feild type

Comment: Submit your content to Solr again like you did the first time. Issue a deleteByQuery (the web admin interface should give you the option to do that directly IIRC) to remove all documents first if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `string` as `fieldtype` for your field `name`.

Apply the String as `fieldtype` and reindex the data.

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

`String` stores the word/sentence as an exact string without performing any tokenization on it.
Its useful in cases for storing exact matches, e.g, for faceting, sorting.

Opposite of `string` type is `text`.
`Text` does the tokenization of data, performs processing such as lower-casing etc. It is helpful in case when we want to match part of a sentence.

If you want achieve the lowercase search then use the below fieldtype for you field.

```
<fieldType name="forExactMatch" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Then your field defination will look like below

```
<field name="name" type="forExactMatch" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: I really apprecate you answer but I cant edit schema files.It is having a text type in schema file.I need some other approach

Comment: try using edismax and use the phrase search and give higher boosting

Comment: can you add example demo I am reaaly a beigner and I dont know about how to boost.It wil be a great help atleast if you add a demo

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=ship to add&defType=edismax&mm=3

Comment: try /select?bq=name:(ship to add)^50&bq=name:(ship to)^20&defType=edismax

Comment: It is still not giving me exact search result like if i search plant it gives me plant number plant type etc and then on 5th position i get "plant" search

Comment: that will happen...if you dont modify the schema as suggested

Comment: even after I have changed schema results are same

Comment: you need to re-index the data