# Solr how to get only the exact match

Tags: solr, exact-match, solr-search

Sample tags field.

```
"tags":["[\"Rectangle\",\"Product\",\"Font\",\"Rectangle\",\"Product\",\"Rectangle\",\"Snack\",\"Product\",\"Material property\",\"Product\",\"Material property\"]"],
```

When I search the keyword land in the tags field I get the results that contain land vehicle

```
q=tags:land

"tags":["[\"Land vehicle\",\"Vehicle\"]"] -
```

I do not want this to produce a match.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" igno reCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="tags" type="text_general">
```

[image: Screenshot of an example document with the tags field as described above]

Comment: Use String as the field type..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640474/solr-search-not-giving-exact-result-for-single-word-term/64640531#64640531

Comment: I have changed my schema as below

<field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>

<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" docValues="true"/>

After changing, now I'm not getting any results 

Note: the field has values in comma separated

"tags":["["Rectangle","Product","Font","Rectangle","Product","Rectangle","Snack","Product","Material property","Product","Material property"]"],

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: It seems like you have a JSON string indexed as a single string, instead of as separate fields? You should make that index separate values instead (by decoding it as JSON and then indexing it properly) - how does your indexing code look? What is actually returned with your document?

Comment: @MatsLindh i have attached a image of a sample document

Comment: Yeah, that's broken data. You should deserialize it first, then add it as proper a proper mulivalued field. It's being sent as serialized JSON, which won't behave properly (i.e. the serialized string will be indexed as a single value). You should also add textual content as proper text in your question, since it will be far more accessible and searchable in those cases.